# Filter orders within JOIN just the items i selected via a checkbox

Tags: mysql, join, checkbox, filter

MYSQL

I want to filter "orders" according to their items within a form's checkboxes.

For example,
I checked
ITEM A + ITEM B , but not ITEM C

## ORDER 1

ITEM A

## ORDER 2

ITEM B

## ORDER 3

ITEM A

ITEM B

ITEM C

## ORDER 4

ITEM A

ITEM B

What i want to have is:

ORDER 1 & ORDER 2 & ORDER 4 ,but not ORDER 3 because this has also ITEM C

MY QUERY LIKE THIS

```
SELECT
P.id as product_id,P.name as product_name,
O.id as order_id,O.group_id,O.payment_date,O.payment_type_id,I.quantity,
M.name,M.surname,M.email
FROM tbl_orders O
LEFT JOIN tbl_order_items I on I.order_id = O.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_products P on P.id = I.product_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_members M on M.id = O.member_id
WHERE
     I.product_id in (1044,1129,20976,16775)
AND
     O.status_id = 311 and O.payment_status_id = 349
```

Thank you

Comment: How does your query relate to your example?

Comment: Its the logic, just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the core problem is that you want to EXCLUDE orders which have any of the unchecked values, and INCLUDE orders which have at least one of the checked values.

```
SELECT
P.id as product_id,P.name as product_name,
O.id as order_id,O.group_id,O.payment_date,O.payment_type_id,I.quantity,
M.name,M.surname,M.email
FROM tbl_orders O -- start with orders

-- add in the items, but use INNER to avoid orders that do not have
-- at least one order_item whose id was checked
INNER JOIN tbl_order_items I on I.order_id = O.id
           AND I.product_id in (1044,1129,20976,16775)
-- left join in the items which were NOT checked.  If there are any, the
-- rows will have bad product ids in them.
-- But if there ARE NOT any bad items in the order, 
-- then there will only be one row with NULL for BADITEMS.product_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_order_items BADITEMS on BADITEMS.order_id = O.id
           AND BADITEMS.product_id NOT in (1044,1129,20976,16775)
-- Pull in the product information
INNER JOIN tbl_products P on P.id = I.product_id
-- Pull in member information
LEFT JOIN tbl_members M on M.id = O.member_id
WHERE
     -- the inner join has already insured that we only get orders
     -- that have checked items.
     -- To remove the orders that ALSO had unchecked items,
     -- We take only rows where the BADITEMS join failed.
     BADITEMS.product_id IS NULL
AND
     O.status_id = 311 and O.payment_status_id = 349
```